# Sum of Squares homework

Tags: assembly

With sum of squares a^2+b^2==? I am trying to write a straight down code for this in the [HMMM 
(Harvey Mudd Miniature Machine)](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~cs5grad/cs5/hmmm/documentation/documentation.html) assembly language (running in my Python IDLE IDE).  Right now I have

```
0 read r1 #read number given 
1 read r2 #read number given 
2 mul r1 r1 r1 #multiply number times itself 
3 mul r2 r2 r2 #multiply number times itself 
4 add r3 r1 r2 #add the two numbers 
5 write r3 #write the new number
```

This is a homework assignment for school.  My teacher said online help is ok as long as I cite where the help came from.

This is our second homework assignment so it isn't supposed to be very hard I just think im missing a crucial step, or im completely wrong or something.

Comment: Can you run your code? What are the inputs and outputs?

Comment: Looking at the HMMM documentation, you may need a halt command.

Comment: Ask your instructor or a TA for help with how to use the computer.  If you're having trouble even getting the tools to work, then there's too much going on for this to be a single useful question on SO.

Comment: I've put your question on hold because it is missing crucial information; we can't tell what is going wrong because you didn't tell us. Always include what inputs you gave the program, what *should* happen (expected output), and what happens instead (including full error messages if there are any). Without those, the question is not useful for future visitors as they can't determine if they have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code works (with the addition of a halt command), so 9/10 for that. I couldn't figure out how to use IDLE, so I just ran the HMMM assembler and simulator from the Windows command line. This is what I got:

```
D:\Users\Mick\Development\Eclipse\HMMM>hmmmAssembler.py
Enter input file name: sum_squares.ha

----------------------
| ASSEMBLY SUCCESSFUL |
----------------------

0 : 0000 0001 0000 0001        0 read r1 #read number given
1 : 0000 0010 0000 0001        1 read r2 #read number given
2 : 1000 0001 0001 0001        2 mul r1 r1 r1 #multiply number times itself
3 : 1000 0010 0010 0010        3 mul r2 r2 r2 #multiply number times itself
4 : 0110 0011 0001 0010        4 add r3 r1 r2 #add the two numbers
5 : 0000 0011 0000 0010        5 write r3 #write the new number
6 : 0000 0000 0000 0000        6 halt


D:\Users\Mick\Development\Eclipse\HMMM>hmmmsimulator.py
Enter debugging mode? no
Enter number: 2
Enter number: 3
13

D:\Users\Mick\Development\Eclipse\HMMM>
```

HTH :)

Comment: Thank you! I actually found out it worked once i inputted it into an online assembler i just had to do setn (then number) twice to give the code my desired numbers then halt.